# WordPress Admin Role and which one to setup

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, admin

i have recently setup a wordpress/woocommerce site and now need to handover this to someone who can add products, edit, delete products etc. The only features I dont want him to have control over is editing the template code. I have setup an Editor Profile but I have been told the Products section does not show up in admin and I was wondering how i go about fixing this.

Would appreciate some advice as its my first Wordpress site.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give assign the user 'shop manager' role.

Comment: Thank you thats what i just did and all works as i needed it.